# Adding parentheses to figure references

Tags: cross-referencing, punctuation

Using pretty much no packages, when using the `\ref{label of figure}` i get just the number of the figure. 
Is there an easy way to set it to make parentheses around that number?
 At the moment I have to do it manually, but would be nicer if it could be done automatically

Comment: Are you comfortable with that happening for *all* references? Including those to a table, a section, an equation, ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You could create a little macro, say `\newcommand\pref[1]{(\ref{#1})}` -- short for "parenthetical `\ref`", I suppose -- and place it in the preamble. Then, write `\pref{<label of figure>}`. The point is that by creating the macro `\pref` you need not modify the default behavior of `\ref`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\p@figure` macro that's used in building the current label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@figure{\expandafter\counter@parenthesize}
\newcommand\counter@parenthesize[1]{(#1)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{X}\label{X}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{X}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can do similarly for the other counters you need to be treated in a similar way.