# How to put parentheses in black when references is in an other color

Tags: cross-referencing, color, punctuation

This question is related to this post: 
[Adding parentheses to figure references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166138/adding-parentheses-to-figure-references/166149#166149)

How can I have black parentheses when the references are in blue when using the mentioned macro?

I have applied the blue color to my all references but I get that the parentheses for the figure references turn blue contrary to the ones of the author and equation references that keep the black color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{backref=true,
    colorlinks=true,
         linkcolor=blue,
          }

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@figure{\expandafter\counter@parenthesize}
\newcommand\counter@parenthesize[1]{(#1)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{X}\label{X}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{X}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple method is to use a separate color of for the parenthese. This can be achieved by:

```
\newcommand\counter@parenthesize[1]{\textcolor{black}{(}#1\textcolor{black}{)}}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! thanks very much for your prompt help Marco Daniel!